# Raising UI event handler from inside serial port event handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, serial-port

I have a simple Windows Forms application that receives telemetry via a serial interface and presents it using bars and numbers in a small window.

Being a complete beginner in C#, and having by no means mastered the concept of object oriented programming, I put it together mainly by reading others' code.

The architecture is very simple and pragmatic. I have an event handler that reads and parses the incoming byte stream and when a complete message has been received it sets a global boolean to true. In parallel there is a periodical event checking for this global boolean to be true and if so, updating the display. I would prefer to either simply update the display from within the serial port event handler (it is very simple, just updating the value of a few progress bars and labels) or have the display update event raised by a message received instead of periodical. I have not been able to do either, I struggle to get my head around the public/private/thread mechanics.

Here is some pseudo code of my application:

```
namespace ACOM_Controller
{ 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OpenSerial(); // open serial port with correct speed etc.
            port.DataReceived += Port_OnReceiveData; // DataReceived Event Handler
            // Set up timer with 50ms period for updating display
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimer);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private static void Port_OnReceiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Parse and decode telemetry messages over serial port
            // Set NewMessageAvailable = true every time done
        }

        private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NewMessageAvailable)
            {
                // Update displayed dat/bars
                NewMessageAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say you have not been able to do it, what have you tried so far, and what problems has that brought up?

Comment: Can you clarify what does not work for you? but I think that the problem in your application that you are trying to update UI elements from a background thread, you can start from there.

Comment: Yes. Being an old C programmer I don't think threads... What I would like to do is to get rid of the timer mechanics and instead trigger the OnTimer event handler from inside the Port_OnReceiveData event handler every time a complete message has been received. Or get rid of the OnTimer event handler altogether and simply update the UI elements from inside it. I have not been able to do either. I am not sure if I am just ignorant of the correct syntax or if the threading/encapsulation is getting in the way.

Comment: You can remove timer and try following code inside `Port_OnReceiveData()` when you want to update UI elements `this.Invoke(new Action(() => { //Update UI elements here}));`. By using this code you are running it in UI thread so you can update UI elements.

Comment: Thanks! It was something like this I was looking for. However it seems "this" is not defined/unambigous within Port_OnReceiveData().

Comment: `this` should relate to current object; I think you get this error because your function is static I did not notice it earlier, if static is not required remove it, and if it is required then try to use same invoke code in timer handler.

Comment: Thanks. I removed static (not really sure if it is needed) and now "this" is defined but I get an error message that method Invoke is not defined for MainWindow. Putting the Invoke inside the timer handler sort of defeats the purpose since the whole purpose is to get rid of it.

Comment: I got some advice from elsewhere - using Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke it was perfectly possible to access the UI elements from inside the serial data event handler! Thanks anyway for your pointers!

Comment: Yes, this is another way to do it, Welcome.